# Decrypting a devise password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, devise, passwords

I need to decrypt a password generated by devise.

For example, my password is `test123test`. devise generated this password:

```
$2a$10$vGeVVu.E0XGjlNEa0xMCK.R0SEH0aFuyJpefrq01Axz6WSbHApPEu
```

I need to decrypt the password and send `test123test`.

Comment: Decrypting passwords is designed to be extremely computationally expensive. It's a lot faster to encrypt one and compare it to the result of a previously encrypted one, than it is to try to decrypt it. That's the basis for a lot of password attacks using dictionaries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't, that's the whole point.

Bcrypt will allow you compare `test123test` with `$2a$10$vGeVVu.E0XGjlNEa0xMCK.R0SEH0aFuyJpefrq01Axz6WSbHApPEu`, but it will never give you the plain text password back. You might want to ask how to crack a bcrypt encrypted password instead (Very hard! Nearly impossible I think)

Jose Valim describes the motivation behind choosing bcrypt by linking to http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ from the devise Google Group.

Answer (score 3):

Use the recoverable module in Devise to reset the user's password.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable,
     :recoverable, :timeoutable, :trackable, :validatable, :rememberable
```

Devise will generate a password reset form and will send the user an email with the password reset link.  The user clicks on the link, resets their password and signs in again.

Answer (score 2):

What Leito said is right. You cannot get plain text password back or may take long long time to find. One other thing is you can check whether given password equals to encrypted one by bcrypt-calculator.

[bcrypt-calculator](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator)

> a.Look for BCrypt Tester
>
> b.enter the password you want to check ex : test123test
>
> c.enter the devise encrypted password ex : $2a$10$vGeVVu.E0XGjlNEa0xMCK.R0SEH0aFuyJpefrq01Axz6WSbHApPEu
>
> press calculate.To find Password and hash match

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I have passed params like

<ActionController::Parameters {"data"=>{"attributes"=>{"email"=>"venkateshkarni+u47@gmail.com", "old_password"=>"pass", "activated"=>"true", "password"=>"pass", "password_confirmation"=>"pass"}}, "controller"=>"account_block/accounts", "action"=>"change_password", "account"=>{}} permitted: false>

```
  account_params = jsonapi_deserialize(params)

  @user_account = User.find_by(email: account_params["email"])
  @encrypt = BCrypt::Password.new(@user_account.password_digest)
  if @encrypt == account_params["old_password"]
    update_pass = @user_account.update(password: account_params['password'])
      return render json: {message: 'You have successfully change password.'}, status: :ok
  else
    return render json: {errors: [
        {account: "You've entered incorrect password."},
      ]}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```