# How do I view users and passwords in rails terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, spree

I'm building a site that uses `Devise` for logins.  I thought I set the admin name to `admin@admin.com` and the password to `testing123`, but it's not working.  I saw another post on here that said I can just go into the irb and type

```
y User.all
```

and all the users would come up with their info.  That's not working.  I just want to call it up to see what the admin name and password are so I don't have to rebuild everything all over again.  Can someone help with this?

Comment: You can never get the password back since it's hashed. You can change the password of a user by setting the `password` attribute.

Comment: check here rails update_all http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting a devise password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253796/decrypting-a-devise-password)

Answer (score 7):

### This is how you do it.

1. Enter your Rails Console `rails c` from your Terminal.
2. See all users `User.all`
3. Find a user by email `User.where(email: "foo@bar.com")` will return the user if it matches the email (you can search by any model attributes) to see which attributes your User model has you can do `User` and that will output the User model structure.
4. Grab a user and store it in a variable `usr = User.first` (grab the first user, you can use `where` to find x user as well, then store it in the usr variable to reference it later). Example using `where`: `usr = User.where(email: "foo@bar.com").first`.
5. Change the email and password of the first user `usr.update_attributes(email: "another@email.com", password: "newpassword123")` now you just successfully changed the email and password of the first user of the database `usr.email` will output `"another@email.com"` and `usr.password` will output an the password you set but encrypted, but you can now use your new credentials to log in or do whatever you want.

***Note***: `rails c` will access your `development` environment, if you want to access your production environment (for example in heroku) you do `heroku run rails c`.

Comment: I used this answer as a basis but slightly different commands, and perhaps this is because the API has been changed so hopefully it adds value:

To change the root password, User.all is to get the root user id, or whatever id you need:

`bundle exec rails console
User.all
usr = User.where(id: "1").first
usr.update_attribute("password", "newpassword123")
`

Answer (score 3):

I would go into rails console with rails c while in the directory. Then I would type :

```
user = User.find_by(email: "admin@admin.com")
```

that way if you need to update it you can do

```
user.update(password: "your password")
```

(just make sure that the password field is called password. If not, adjust the code whatever the field is called)

`User.all` should give you an active record collection proxy( array) of all of your users.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your irb

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.update(password: "testing123", password_confirmation: "testing123")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enter the Rails Console by taping => `rails c` or `rails console`

then search for your info like this => `user = User.find_by(email: "admin@admin.com")`

then simply do this => `user.password = "your new password"`

then => `user.save!`